# Can an axe musket be used one handed to make melee attacks? Does it function as a battle axe for abilities?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

> This short musket features an axe blade at the end of its barrel. It can be used as both a musket and a battleaxe. It is considered a double weapon for the purposes of creating masterwork or magical versions of this weapon. If this firearm gains the broken condition, both the firearm component and the axe are considered broken. An axe musket uses either a bullet and a single dose of black powder or an alchemical cartridge as ammunition. This is an early firearm.

As the weapon functions as a battle axe and a musket, can one make the melee attack with the battle axe with one hand, as a battle axe is typically a one handed weapon?

If so, how does it react with abilities like the magus' Spellstrike, which requires a one-handed melee weapon? Does the axe musket, held in one hand, count for that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Axe Musket is only treated as a double weapon in the context of crafting and enchanting. When wielding the weapon you must choose which end you are using and it effectively becomes that weapon; You cannot wield both at the same time as you would with a normal double weapon.

But this means you may also use the axe end with feats and abilities that require a one-handed melee, including the Magus' Spellstrike feature.

Comment: The rules citation for my response would be the OP's own quote. Also, to paraphrase: "It can be used as both a musket and a battleaxe" would mean that it can be used in exactly the same manner a regular battleaxe could when wielded that way.